# Bulk change link to pdf's

Tags: links

Good morning,
I installed first my site on a staging server. So that all the links to pdf files are such as : `https://mystagingserver.com/wp-content/uploads/%date%/%filename%.pdf`
Now that my site is running on public server, is it possible to bulk change the links of the buttons who send to this pdfs so that I have in the button's link that result:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/%date%/%filename%.pdf
```

I found that the pdf files with this new names are yet existing after migration on public server. It's just the link of the buttons who send to the staging server.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd try [wp-cli search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) - after you've taken a database backup of course.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll suggest your idea to my developer because its a little too difficult for me.